# How to fix 'System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am new to Xml and Linq and I have been following a tutorial on youtube on how to use it.

Link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OsfVJ485RY4

The problem is that when I run the code to either change the value or delete it, I always get the following error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Attribute(...) returned null.
```

**First of all I load my document:**

```
XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\matpl\source\repos\LinqToXML\LinqToXML\Data.xml");
```

**The part where I want to change the value of the Xml document**

```
xmlDocument.Element("Students")
           .Elements("Student")
           .Where(x => x.Attribute("Id").Value == "101").FirstOrDefault()
           .SetElementValue("TotalMarks", "999");
```

**When I want to delete an element:**

```
xmlDocument.Root.Elements().Where(x => x.Attribute("Id").Value == "104").Remove();
```

**XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--Comment Updated-->
<Students>
  <Student>
    <Student Id='101'>
      <Name>Mark</Name>
      <Gender>Male</Gender>
      <TotalMarks>800</TotalMarks>
    </Student>
    <Student Id='102'>
      <Name>Rosy</Name>
      <Gender>Female</Gender>
      <TotalMarks>900</TotalMarks>
    </Student>
    <Student Id='103'>
      <Name>Pam</Name>
      <Gender>Female</Gender>
      <TotalMarks>850</TotalMarks>
    </Student>
    <Student Id='104'>
      <Name>John</Name>
      <Gender>Male</Gender>
      <TotalMarks>950</TotalMarks>
    </Student>
  </Student>
  <Student Id='105'>
    <Name>Todd</Name>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <TotalMarks>980</TotalMarks>
  </Student>
</Students>
```

Thank you,

Comment: The best way is to check step by step. Firstly on Students element, then in Student etc. until you get null to your variable. By the way I think you have student element twice so it stops on the first one and you want to pass on the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one more `Student` element between `Students` and `Student-101`. It looks like you have wrong xml:

```
<Students>
  <Student> //WHAT IS IT?
    <Student Id='101'>
      <Name>Mark</Name>
      <Gender>Male</Gender>
      <TotalMarks>800</TotalMarks>
    </Student>
    <Student Id='102'>
      <Name>Rosy</Name>
      <Gender>Female</Gender>
      <TotalMarks>900</TotalMarks>
    </Student>
    <Student Id='103'>
      <Name>Pam</Name>
      <Gender>Female</Gender>
      <TotalMarks>850</TotalMarks>
    </Student>
    <Student Id='104'>
      <Name>John</Name>
      <Gender>Male</Gender>
      <TotalMarks>950</TotalMarks>
    </Student>
  </Student> //WHAT IS IT?
  <Student Id='105'>
    <Name>Todd</Name>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <TotalMarks>980</TotalMarks>
  </Student>
</Students>
```

Check this https://dotnetfiddle.net/14js9r. It works without errors with proper xml.

Comment: Thank you, I was always looking at my code and not my xml document, removing both wrong lines fixed my problem.